# How do I kill the Application Switcher?

Tags: macos, mac, graphics, bug, application-switcher

All of the sudden the Application Switcher's graphics breaks:

[image: Screenshot of the 16 color Application Switcher]

Restart does help, but became a nuisance. How can I kill it? Restart it?

UPDATE: Logging off fixed this.

UPDATE 2: I came to a conclusion that this is a result of [a conflict in the display cached data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29958/how-to-reset-the-display-cached-data).

Comment: I've removed your second question, if you want you can ask it again **as a separate question**. But since you no longer have this problem, the question might not have a definitive answer.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Here's a [screenshot](http://d.pr/Ikqs) for further reference.

Comment: Your other post to which you linked suggests that this isn't "all of a sudden" but rather in response to hot swapping monitors. If that is the case, please update this question, or combine the two into a single post containing all the information.

Answer (score 10):

It's provided by Dock.app. So you could try `osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'` or `killall "Dock"`.

Comment: Thanks. I did try 'killall Dock' and 'killall Finder' -- no luck there.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to kill `UIServer`?

You can either try `killall UIServer` or find it on **Activity Monitor** and kill it from there.

Comment: Thanks; though it didn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What helps for me is choosing a new color display profile in preferences. Now the graphic corruption is gone for the app switcher.

Answer (score 0):

You could reboot your machine, or log out of the user account and log back in. If the problem is not recurring, that might be your best bet. If this problem happens often, obviously that isn't a good long-term solution, but for a rare occurrence, that might work.