# How do I reset the Display cached data?

Tags: display, color

A week ago I noticed a weird Lion symptom, and [posted a vague description of one this problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29226/how-to-kill-application-switcher).

Today, after some tests, I came to a conclusion that this bug reproduces whenever a the computer is logged into while plugged to a certain display, and then being plugged to a different display.

The only thing I can think of is that the display data is saved, and a conflict occurs upon the plugging of a different display.

Any idea as to how I can delete or reset this data?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I've found that logging out from the current user and logging back in again resets the Application Switcher. So far, sad to say, this is the only "solution" to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Maybe this will work: *System Preferences > Displays > Detect Displays*

Comment: I did. I'm experiencing this problem with an Apple Cinema Display and some old LG display. Probably type specific.

Comment: hmmm, I have a few questions. What mac are you using (pro, macbook, imac)? How are you connecting the displays (DVI, VGA, HDMI [any adaptors])? Is it still just the application switcher that has the graphical issues, or are there other problems as well?